# After upgrading to mysql 5.7.21: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, settings

After upgrading to mysql `5.7.21` from `5.7.20` I get an error

```
SELECT ac.vatcode_id,ac.vatcode_type,v.name vatcode_name,v.txt vatcode_txt
FROM `accounting` ac
LEFT JOIN `vatcode` v ON v.id=ac.vatcode_id
WHERE ac.account_id=300479 && ac.vatcode_id>=0 && ac.time BETWEEN 1514764800 AND 1546214400 && ac.block_id=4431
GROUP BY ac.vatcode_id
```

> #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dynaccount.ac.vatcode_type' which is
>   not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
# show variables;
sql_mode
STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: Well, at least the DBMS tells you now that your query is invalid SQL, which is a great improvement, isn't it? You group by `ac.vatcode_id`, but your database cannot guarantee that there is only one `ac.vatcode_type` per `ac.vatcode_id`.

Comment: I don't get it :) how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is invalid. You tell the DBMS: "per `ac.vatcode_id` give me the `ac.vatcode_type`". And the DBMS tells you that there is no *the* `ac.vatcode_type` per `ac.vatcode_id`; there can be multiple different ones. So which do you want? The maximum? Then make this `MAX(ac.vatcode_type)`. The minimum? Then make it `MIN(ac.vatcode_type)`. You don't care which? Then make this `ANY_VALUE(ac.vatcode_type)`.

Your new MySQL version is simply more strict and wants you to write valid queries complying with the SQL standard. This is a good thing.